# Regex: how to get \b to work with utf-8 charset?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to remove words shorter than 3 characters from string, and came up with this regex: `!\b[\pL\pN]{1,2}\b!u` which works in general, but breaks on most of polish characters (ąćęłńśżź), which are treated as non letter symbols and word boundaries (and splits words in the middle if offending char happen to be there).

Sample code to demonstrate this phenomenon:

```
$text = " ää äaa aaäaaa ââ âaa aaâaa ąą ąaa aaąaaa àà áá ââ ãã åå ää ææ ßß ćć èè êê ëë ęę éé ìì íí îî ïï öö òò ôô õõ øø óó ùù úú ûû üü ąą ćć ęę łł ńń óó śś żż źź ";
echo "<h1>input</h1><p>$text</p>";
$text = preg_replace('!\b[\pL\pN]{1,2}\b!u', 'X', $text);
echo "<h1>output</h1><p>$text</p>";
```

Gives output (note aaąaaa being split):

```
input
ää äaa aaäaaa ââ âaa aaâaa ąą ąaa aaąaaa àà áá ââ ãã åå ää ææ ßß ćć èè êê ëë ęę éé ìì íí îî ïï öö òò ôô õõ øø óó ùù úú ûû üü ąą ćć ęę łł ńń óó śś żż źź 

output
X äaa aaäaaa X âaa aaâaa ąą ąX XXaaa X X X X X X X X ćć X X X ęę X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X ąą ćć ęę łł ńń X śś żż źź
                                 ^split
```

Setting different locale with setlocale() didn't help.

Using PHP 5.3.0 on Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot make `\b` work. It only matches ASCII word boundaries. http://www.mail-archive.com/pcre-dev@exim.org/msg00110.html

But you could try to use negative assertions `(?<!\pL)` and `(?!\pL)` in place of the `\b` test.

Comment: Note though that `\b` includes also start and end of string anchors. So you will need to use a positive lookahead with negated character class: `(?<=\PL|^)` and `(?=\PL|$)`.

Comment: It does work strictly \*by accident\* here. A negative assertion will also work at the start or end of the subject, because there is nothing that *could* match.

Comment: Ouh, I thought `u` modifier affects `/b` and makes it work with unicode chars, was wondering why it works for certain chars (which turns out to be regular ascii chars, doh), but not for polish chars. Anyway, works like a charm, many thanks.

Comment: @mario: Some +1s to you for a) Pointing out that your code works, too and b) making me accidentally find out about the awesome `\K` escape sequence :)

Comment: @mario: And another set of +1s for your "About Me" field ;)

Comment: @nikic: That's an interesting escape, albeit I only ever used it to reduce preg_match_all output. And I'm still wondering if `\K` really means Kill switch  :?

Comment: @mario: I think that `\K` could be useful in many places I currently use `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`. (Though I'm not yet sure which of both is the better option.)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
'~(?<=[\PL\PN]|^)[\pL\pN]{1,2}(?=[\PL\PN]|$)~u'
```

This matches any letter or number, which is

- preceded by something that isn't a letter or number or by the start of the string
- followed by something that isn't a letter or number or by the end of the string

Comment: Thanks nikic, I know you were first to answer but I went with mario's one as he pointed out flaw in my knowledge, and his version is bit simpler. Upvote nonetheless.

Comment: It will not work. I've tested with simplest example: `$string = 'hello world';`

Answer (score 2):

I am using following regex.

```
$regExp = '(?<=[\s\p{P}\p{S}\p{C}]|^)('.$search.')(?=[\s\p{P}\p{S}\p{C}]|$)';
```

On my experience simple excluding ([^\p{L}\p{N}]) will not work, because some languages (like hindi/devanagari or japanese) have hidden symbols (vovels symbols), that shows as part of previous or next symbol.